# how to identify sessions being run by the google play store’s review process?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play, ionic4

Every time a new version of my app is pushed to the google play store they load it on multiple real devices and do some automated clicking around.  This happens for *every* version on all tracks.

This in turn produces a lot of bogus page views, and other unnecessary events. At low volumes this really screws with the overall analytics picture. Even at higher volumes, as we aim to have more frequent releases on all tracks I could see it continue to be a nuisance.

I’m looking for a way to detect if a session is being run within these automated processes so that I can add a flag and track them appropriately.

Platform is Ionic 4 on Capacitor

Comment: Are you using firebase for the events?

Comment: No, I'm not using firebase for their events.  "events" in OP is a broad term to include page views, user creation, analytics, etc...